# Parallax Images showing on desktop but not on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, parallax

I am having an issue where my parallax images are not showing up on my mobile device, despite showing perfectly fine on my desktop and while using the mobile inspect view on Chrome. I've tried clearing the cache on my mobile device and still not use it, I have also tried on multiple different mobile devices.

Here is a link to the website in question: https://kojinagatabrown.me/

Here is my Code:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

/* HOME */
.welcome {
  padding-top: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 500px;
  position: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#welcome-line {
  width: 25%;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.welcome h1 {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.welcome h3 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.welcome div {
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
}

/* SCHOOL */
.education-container {
  padding-top: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective-origin: 0%;
}

.education-container div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.education-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: left;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 20rem;
}

.education-text h3 {
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.education-text p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.learn-more {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #05cbf7;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px white solid;
}

.learn-more:hover {
  background-color: #0083a1;
  color: white;
}

#uofu {
  background: url(https://www.kojinagatabrown.me/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/BlockU_400px-300x300.png);
  width: 178px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-origin: border-box;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

/* WORK */
.work-container {
  padding-top: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective-origin: 0%;
}

.work-container div {
  padding: 10px;
}

#eaw {
  background: url("https://www.kojinagatabrown.me/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/EAWlogo-300x79.png");
  width: 200px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-origin: border-box;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.work-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: left;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 20rem;
}

.work-text h3 {
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.work-text p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* DEVICE SPECIFIC PROPERTIES */

/* mobile devices (320-479) */
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  #uofu {
    background-size: 40%;
    background-position: right 2% bottom 50%;
  }

  .education-text h3 {
    margin-top: 50%;
  }

  #eaw {
    background-size: 35%;
    background-position: left 7% bottom 50%;
  }

  .work-text h3 {
    margin-top: 80%;
  }
}

/* tablets (481-769) */
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  #uofu {
    background-size: 40%;
    background-position: right 1% bottom 50%;
  }

  .education-text h3 {
    margin-top: 40%;
  }

  #eaw {
    background-size: 35%;
    background-position: left 6% bottom 50%;
  }

  .work-text h3 {
    margin-top: 55%;
  }
}

/* small screens (770-1023) */
@media screen and (min-width: 770px) {
  #uofu {
    background-size: 25%;
    background-position: right 4% bottom 50%;
  }

  .education-text h3 {
    margin-top: 30%;

  }

  .education-text {
    flex-basis: 35rem;
    margin-left: 4%;
  }

  #eaw {
    background-size: 25%;
    flex-basis: 4rem;
    margin-left: 4%;
    background-position: left 9% bottom 50%;
  }

  .work-text h3 {
    margin-top: 40%;
  }
}

/* medium screens (laptops) (1024-1365) */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  #uofu {
    background-size: 17%;
    background-position: right 17% bottom 50%;
  }

  .education-text h3 {
    margin-top: 27%;
  }

  .education-text {
    flex-basis: 35rem;
    margin-left: 5%;
  }

  #eaw {
    background-size: 20%;
    background-position: left 10% bottom 50%;
    margin-left: 5%;
  }

  .work-text h3 {
    margin-top: 25%;
  }

  .work-text {
    flex-grow: 2;
  }
}

/* large screens (large laptops) (1366-1535) */
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
  #uofu {
    background-size: 15%;
    background-position: right 17% bottom 50%;
  }

  .education-text h3 {
    margin-top: 20%;
  }

  .education-text {
    flex-basis: 45rem;
    margin-left: 7%;
  }

  #eaw {
    background-size: 18%;
    background-position: left 16% bottom 50%;
    margin-left: 7%;
  }

  .work-text h3 {
    margin-top: 20%;
  }

  .work-text {
    flex-grow: 2;
  }
}

/* desktop screens (1536-1919) */
@media screen and (min-width: 1536px) {
  #uofu {
    background-size: 13%;
    background-position: right 20% bottom 50%;
  }

  .education-text h3 {
    margin-top: 20%;
  }

  .education-text {
    flex-basis: 45rem;
    margin-left: 7%;
  }

  #eaw {
    background-size: 18%;
  }

  .work-text {
    flex-grow: 2;
  }
}

/* high resolution screens (1920+) */
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
  #uofu {
    background-size: 15%;
    background-position: right 23% bottom 50%;
  }

  .education-text h3 {
    margin-top: 19%;
  }

  .education-text {
    flex-basis: 45rem;
    margin-left: 9%;
  }

  #eaw {
    background-size: 16%;
    background-position: left 13% bottom 50%;
  }

  .work-text {
    flex-grow: 3;
  }

  .work-text h3 {
    margin-top: 13%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body style="color: white; font-family: Trebuchet MS">
  </body>

  <div class="welcome">
    <h1 style="color: white">
      KOJI NAGATA-BROWN
    </h1>
    <hr id="welcome-line">
    <h3>
      Hello, my name is Koji. Let me tell you about myself.
    </h3>
  </div>

  <div class="education-container">
    <div class="education-text">
      <h3>
       EDUCATION
      </h3>
      <p>
        Currently a junior at the University of Utah, majoring in Computer Science. Tracks in Web/Mobile Development, and Software Development. Planned graduation is Spring of 2023.
      </p>
      <button class="learn-more">
        Learn More!
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="uofu"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="work-container">
    <div id="eaw"></div>
    <div class="work-text">
      <h3>
        WORK EXPERIENCE
      </h3>
      <p>
        I have worked at Education at Work for almost 2 years. During my time I have provided
        technical support for customers using Windows and Microsoft Office.
      </p>
      <button class="learn-more">
      Learn More!
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

Let me know what you guys think, I think it might have something to do with resource allocation on mobile devices, but I don't understand why it would show in the mobile view on desktop, but not on an actual mobile device. Thanks in advance.